# Highlighting Marker on Google Map

Tags: google-maps

Suppose we plot a number of points (latitude, longitude) on the google map using Plot Google map package of R. These points are classified on the basis of unique vehicle-id i.e. a point to represent where a particular vehicle stopped. So, the data consists of numerous vehicles. Now, I just wanted to know whether its possible if we click on a particular legend(marker) on the Google map, then all the legend(marker) of that particular vehicle-id gets highlighted. 
I just wanted to know whether it could be done or how to do it.

```
vehicle_id  longt   latit
19969     86.3607   23.80903333
19969     86.346225 23.7921
23384   86.0130875  23.78897883
23384   86.04025    23.840275
23384   86.1597922  23.914832
23384   86.72869833 23.8198765
23395   86.00305    23.766375
23395   86.58922857 23.8085
23395   86.2883     23.82095
23400   86.01176667 23.78473333
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, you will have to write some javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I found similar solution here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587533/how-to-highlight-map-marker-upon-selection-of-an-html-element/26588306

I hope this can help you...